# Bill of materials service

Tags: web-apps, cms, web-services, saas

I'm looking for flexible and free software for open hardware BOMs.

Key critical features that I need:

- Possibility to save alternatives for each part (another model or
  material)
- Possibility to save alternative suppliers for each part (at least
  name, URL, price)
- Version control
- Automatic generation of product builder with automatic cost
  estimation (like [Virtuemart extension](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/product-builder-for-virtuemar) for Joomla)
- All working as SaaS service and require browser only for work

Desirable features:

- Possibility to fill BOM via markup like Markdown or via GUI form
- Multilanguage support
- Easy unique simple URL for every BOM (like fiddles in jsfiddle.net)
- Mobile-friendly
- Auto-parsing seller info from popular stores, like Ebay, Aliexpress
  etc. Automatic generate printable document you could take with you to
  the store (like  Wunderlist)
- BOM version comparision

I already looked at SAP, Odoo, Tryton and other ERPs which have manufacturing modules, but they are very loaded, complex and require deep integration.
The software most close to my needs is [Arena Solutions](http://www.arenasolutions.com/products/plm/features/bom-management/) (but it's non-free even for open source BOMs and has not all key features)
and Octopart (but it's designed for electronic BOMs only)

Please share your experience, what software are you using for storage and developer your BOMs. Also let me know if you are interested in such a service cause if I wouldn't found suitable solution I will develop my own.